# Passing a SELECT-Statement result to a stored procedure for Temp-Table Join

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to get data from one table in DB-Server-1, and pass it to a stored procedure being executed on DB-SERVER-2 (that joins to this data from DB-Server-1).

So, I have 2 tables on different servers:

1. DB-Server-1: tblItem

   ```
   item_id | item_qty 
   --------+----------
    1231   | 2
    1232   | 4
   ```
2. DB-Server-2: tblItemDetails

   ```
   item_detail_id | item_id | item_data
   ---------------+---------+--------------
    1             | 1231    |  TEST_DATA_1
    2             | 1232    |  TEST_DATA_2
   ```

Now I want to get data from DB-Server-1 (basic select query)

```
SELECT item_id, item_qty
FROM tblItem
WHERE item_id IN (1231, 1232);
```

And pass it to a stored procedure `spSetItemQuantityInItemDetails`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdatePOCartons]
    (@valueList VARCHAR(MAX))
.
.
-- Now trying to split string and create a temp table
-- This temp table will later be used in the SP to join with tblItemDetails to set item_qty

DECLARE @temp TABLE 
(
    item_id int,
    item_qty int
);

DECLARE @pos1 INT
DECLARE @len1 INT
DECLARE @value1 varchar(8000)

DECLARE @pos2 INT
DECLARE @len2 INT
DECLARE @value2 varchar(8000)

SET @valueList = '1,4;2,5;3,14;';

set @pos1 = 0
set @len1 = 0

WHILE CHARINDEX(';', @valueList, @pos1+1)>0
    BEGIN
        set @len1 = CHARINDEX(';', @valueList, @pos1+1) - @pos1
        set @value1 = SUBSTRING(@valueList, @pos1, @len1)
        --SELECT @pos, @len, @value /*this is here for debugging*/

        PRINT @value1;
        -----------

            set @pos2 = 0
            set @len2 = 0

            WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @value1, @pos2+1)>0
                BEGIN
                    set @len2 = CHARINDEX(',', @value1, @pos2+1) - @pos2
                    set @value2 = SUBSTRING(@value1, @pos2, @len2)
                    --SELECT @pos, @len, @value /*this is here for debugging*/

                    PRINT @value2;
                    set @pos2 = CHARINDEX(',', @value1, @pos2+@len2) +1
                END

        ------------
        set @pos1 = CHARINDEX(';', @valueList, @pos1+@len1) +1
    END
```

**Issue**

I am trying to understand if the above solution is closest to what would work (currently it is not splitting last value of string which does not end with ; or , )

OR is there some better approach?

Comment: You can't "pass" result sets to a stored procedure. If you need to pass a dataset, you need to use a table type parameter.

Comment: Do you have control over the SQL Server objects (can you change the stored procedures), or are you simply consuming them from your client application?

Comment: I can change the Stored Proc

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your input. Updated the same

Comment: FYI, there are *far* better ways of splitting a string in SQL than using a `WHILE`. A *well* designed iTVF (i.e. `delimitedsplit8k_LEAD`) an XML splitter, the built in `STRING_SPLIT` (if you're using a supported version of SQL Server), or a CLR function would all be far better methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot everyone. Your insights really helped get to the solution.
I was able to get the expected behaviour via :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tval') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tval;
CREATE TABLE #tval (val1 INT, val2 INT);

declare @s varchar(1000)
set @s = '1,11;2,22'

;WITH cte AS (
  select value
  from string_split(@s, ';')
)

INSERT INTO #tval
    SELECT
       MAX(CASE WHEN ord=1 THEN v END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN ord=2 THEN v END)
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT value AS v, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS ord
    FROM  STRING_SPLIT([value], ',')) s
    GROUP BY value;

SELECT * from #tval
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a better approach might be to pass a table variable directly to the stored procedure. In order to do so, you'd have to create a type that creates a structure for the input table. I recreated this scenario below. Let me know if you can work with this to achieve your goals.

```
--Create test tables
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblItem (item_id int, item_qty int);
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblItem2 (item_detail_id int, item_id int, item_details varchar(50));
GO

--Create the type that can be used as input
CREATE TYPE TableForInput as TABLE
(
    Item_Id int,
    Item_Qty int
);

GO 

--Create/alter the stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetCardData
@Input TableForInput READONLY
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.tblItem2 as t2 INNER JOIN @Input as i ON t2.Item_id = i.Item_id
END

GO

--Insert dummy data into the test tables
INSERT INTO dbo.tblItem values (1231, 2), (1232, 4);
INSERT INTO dbo.tblItem2 VALUES (1, 1231, 'TEST_1'), (2, 1232, 'TEST2')

-- The below would mimic the client side.
-- Declare a local temporary table, select data into it
--      And then pass this as a parameter to the stored proc
DECLARE @Data TableForInput;

INSERT INTO @Data
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblItem;


exec dbo.usp_GetCardData @Data
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind effort. This gives a nice insight. However, in my case I first query into DB-Server-1 from a PHP-DAO, then get the data for tblItem, 
And then basically query to another external StoredProcedure on Server-2 to update table on DB-Server-2 (with different DB-Handler). Thus these will be 2 different executed queries

Comment: Thus I'm trying to update the SProc to take the first table data as argument, then create a temp table from that data inside the SProc, and then Join as regular with the temp table